# Linux scripting: Passing parameters

Tags: linux, scripting, awk

I'm new to scripting and need a lot of help understanding how to load in a text file that will be passed in by a parameter. I'm afraid that you'll have to really dumb down your answers. Please explain like I am a 10 year old!

For example, how does one write a script that accepts two parameters, a file path and an integer.

Also how do you run the script? would you just call `script.sh -f data.txt`

Comment: If you need a "lot of help", you need to [read the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html). If you have a more specific problem, StackOverflow would be a useful place to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you explain your requirement a bit in detail?

I assume you are looking to extract the Nth column from a given file.  You don't need to parse command-line parameters within AWK, instead just pass them from `sh(1)` itself.

```
# foo.sh
awk "{ print $"$1" }" $2
```

Here I'm escaping out of AWK to get the first argument which is the position number.
If you find that too confusing you can manipulate `ARGC`, `ARGV`.  Read `awk(1)`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help. I am trying to write a script that accepts an integer, N, and extracts the Nth column from a text file that is also passed in.

The part i'm specifically stuck on at the moment is i want to write a script that recognises getopts such as -f and -s. Do you have any advice on how to do this?

Comment: @user1136076 AFAIK AWK cannot do it portably, you can use `getopt(1)` and like I had mentioned earlier use `sh(1)` to pass around the params for `awk(1)`.

Comment: You should use the `-v` option to pass shell variable values into AWK variables instead of embedding shell variables directly into an AWK script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by manipulating [`ARGC` and `ARGV`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html) to extract your integer from the argument list in the `BEGIN` block. You can put your script in a text file with the first line being `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` and then make the file executable with `chmod a+x`.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getopt-Function.html#Getopt-Function) of the GNU AWK (`gawk`) manual describes how to process options as `getopt` would.

Include the function shown on that page in your script.