# How can I use shell to transfer java method?

Tags: java, linux, shell

There is a Java demo :

```
package com.demo;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world!");
    }
}
```

How can I use shell to transfer it?

I am not very familiar with `Linux`.  There is a `demand:use shell` to transfer `java` method.

Please tell me or give me a demo.

Comment: What are you actually want to achieve?

Comment: my english is not good ..  I mean , use shell carried out java program and get result...

Comment: Isn't it done the same way on all the operating systems where java is available? With `javac` and `java` executeables.

Comment: Has the Java demo already been compiled?

Answer (score 0):

If by `transfer` you meant run (or execute), then simply do (you have to be in folder where `Demo.class`, compiled version, is)

```
java com.demo.Demo
```

but you have to have java on path, so test that first running

```
java -version
```

from console...

Or you can specify absolute path to java program....

You can write the same command into `hello.sh` if you want, there is not a big difference to have the command in script or execute it from command line.

If your script has to be more general, you should look for [Linux scripting: Passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374706/linux-scripting-passing-parameters) and so on...

Comment: my english is not good...    i mean  use shell execute java program and get result ....     Like this: you give the shell parameters: package name,class name and class method , the shell will execute and get the result...

Comment: Is the above ok for you or not? It assumes, that Demo is in default package (no name), if your package is let say `pack`, command have to be changed to `java pack.Demo` and you have to be in same folder as pack folder is (and in this folder Demo.class should be).

Comment: package com.demo;                                                                                                       public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world!");
    }
}                                                                                                                                                                                  For example:: source hello.sh com.demo Demo main   result is : hello world!  so,please help me to wirte the shell...